# In a CART model, why is the average of the leaf proportions equal to the total proportion only when the classes are unweighted?

Tags: cart, scikit-learn

Suppose I want to do binary classification (the two classes are 0 and 1) and I choose to work with a CART model. I first fit this model on a training set. (Note that I am using Python, and specifically the `sklearn` `DecisionTreeClassifier`.)

Then, for a sample X, `predict_proba` returns `[p0(X), p1(X)]` where `p0(X)` represents the probability that X belongs to the 0-class and `p1(X)` represents the probability that X belongs to the 1-class.

In the `sklearn` documentation, it is said that `p0(X)` is equal to: (number of samples of the training set which belong to the leaf of X and to the 0-class) / (number of samples of the training set which belong to the leaf of X), that is to say the ratio of the 0-class in the leaf of X. And the same way for `p1(X)`.

With this definition, I would think that the average of p0 on the training set itself, is going to be equal to: (number of samples of the training set which belong to the 0-class)/(number of samples of the training set), that is to say the ratio of the 0-class in the training set.

If I put `class_weight=None`, then the previous statement is true. But with any other `class_weight`, it is not anymore and I do not understand why.

Comment: You may want to consider re-titling your question, as this has much more to do with the conceptual structure of a tree model, and little to do with `sklearn` specifically.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, I agree w/ you. I tried to edit this, however, phrasing it was tough. See if you think I represented the question accurately.

Comment: @gung I think that captures my interpretation accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see why this works out in one case, but not the other, by following your nose through the arithmetic.

Say you have a tree $T$, and the terminal nodes are $T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_k$.  Let $N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_k$ denote the number of training data points in each of these terminal nodes.  Then we can write the prediction in terminal node $T_j$ as:

$$ p_j = \frac{\sum_{i \in T_j} y_i}{N_j} $$

So your training average of the predictions is

$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_j N_j \frac{\sum_{i \in T_j} y_i}{N_j}$$

Since this looks a little gnarly, a word of explanation.  Each observation in a terminal node receives the *same* prediction as all the others in the same node, so to aggregate, we can sum over the terminal node predictions, and repeat each summand $N_j$ times.

Now you can see why your equality holds

$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_j N_j \frac{\sum_{i \in T_j} y_i}{N_j} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_j \sum_{i \in T_j} y_i = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i $$

When there are sample weights, the convenient cancellation does not occur, as the prediction in the terminal node is then

$$ p_j = \frac{\sum_{i \in T_j} w_i y_i}{\sum_{i \in T_j} w_i} $$

And there is no reason for $\sum_{i \in T_j} w_i = N_j$ to hold.

A similar thing happens with class weights.